# exchange web services and EOL

Tags: exchangewebservices, office365api

I am planning to access Office 365 mailbox and i want to know whether EWS 2.2 still valid or need to go with Graph API.

I am planning to create a backup solution . and need to know

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If at all possible, use the Graph API.  EWS is in maintenance mode and we are no longer adding features to it.  The only case where you would need to use EWS is if you app also needed to access legacy on-prem Exchange installs since REST wasn't available for previous versions.

Comment: Great .I was looking for this answer from  last couple of days , I hope i can buy you a beer.

Comment: Would Graph API also provide Backups of On Promise Exchange Server

Comment: i got below answer from https://social.msdn.microsoft.com (Vasil L. Michev)

Comment: EWS is still supported with O365/Exchange Online and there are no plans to deprecate support for it. It's used by many migration/backup tools, so you should have no problems using it too.

Comment: True - it will be around for quite some time.  But if at all possible, I would suggest moving to the REST API.  Aside from our new investments being in REST, we have put a lot of effort improving the performance of the REST API which did not accrue to EWS.